# MySQL - Slave SQL Thread not running

Tags: mysql, replication

I have to admit that I am not really good in database administration, still learning. Would be glad if someone could point me a good direction.

This is in my MASTER server `my.ini`.

```
log-bin=mysql-bin.log
server-id=1
sync-binlog=1
binlog-do-db=main_live
```

And this is in my SLAVE server `my.ini`.

```
relay-log=mysql-relay-bin.log
log-bin=mysql-bin.log
binlog-do-db=main_live
replicate-do-db=main_live
```

I expect all tables in `main_live` to be replicated.
But it seems to replicate tables in `main_office` as well.

And this happen:

```
Error 'Table 'main_office.followed_task_user' doesn't exist' on query. Default database: 'main_live'. Query: 'insert into `main_office`.`followed_task_user` (`task_id`, `user_id`) values (3, 212379)'
```

I suspect it has something to do with this default database but I am not sure how to solve this.
Would be glad if someone can point a direction.

Thanks!

Comment: What part of `Table 'main_office.followed_task_user' doesn't exist` don't you understand?

Comment: @EJP The database `main_office` only exists in MASTER server but does not exists in SLAVE server because it is not expected to be replicated at all.

Comment: What is your binlog-format setting?  It probably should be ROW if you want to avoid issues with USE and cross database statements.  Also it's helpful to know the MySQL version.

Comment: @Lunc MASTER's MySQL version is 5.7.3-m13-log and binlog_format is STATEMENT.  SLAVE's MySQL (is actually MariaDB branch) version is 10.1.16-MariaDB.

Comment: Together with binlog-do-db, the `USE` and cross database statements are obviously the culprit.I have read this [link]https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/ and changed from master binlog-do-db to use slave replicate-do-wild-table. Everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: But I have another application constantly read-write a lot (hundreds of rows per second) on another database in master and it seems the storage is growing fast, which was the first reason I have used binlog-do-db. Any recommended resolution to this rapidly growing database which I do not wish to log or replicate at all?